# css - center a 3-column layout <ul>

Tags: php, html, css

I have a listing that is generated by calling an API - the listing for each page is limited to 30 and each column should have 10 listings.

[image]

At the moment it doesn't look centred especially on bigger screens. I tried margin: 0 auto and nothing worked. I can do it manually which I did but that solution is feasible for larger screens and make sure they are responsive (becomes 2 columns and then 1 column on mobile). How do I rectify this problem?

css:

```
#native {

 width: 100%;
 margin: auto;
 padding: 0;
 position: relative;
 left: 2%;
}

#native ul {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline-block;
 padding-right: 65px;
}


@media(max-width: 480px){
#native {
    -moz-column-count: 1;
    -webkit-column-count: 1;
    column-count: 1;
   }
}

@media(max-width: 768px){
#native {
    left: 0;
    -moz-column-count: 2;
    -webkit-column-count: 2;
    column-count: 2;
   }
}


 @media (min-width: 1600px)
 {
   #native {

    max-width: 1600px;

   }
   #native ul {

    padding-right: 150px;

   }
}
```

html/php:

```
<div id="native" class="margin-top-2x">  
    <ul>
        <?php 
           $i=1;
           foreach ( $model as $d ) { ?>
        <?php if ( !empty ( $d['id'] ) ): ?>
            <li>

                    <a href="<?php echo $this->createUrl ( 'frontend/detailedView' , array( 'id' => $d['id'] ) ) ?>"><?php echo ysUtil::truncate($d['title'], 45) ?></a>

                <br>
            </li>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <?php
            if ( ($i % 10) == 0 ) {
                echo "</ul>";
                echo (end ( $model['id'] ) == $d['id']) ? "" : "<ul>";
            }
            $i++;
            ?>
        <?php } ?>
</div>
```

Comment: `margin: 0 auto` works only with some fixed `width`

Comment: have you tried wrapping in a `<div class="align:center">`

Comment: or `<center></center>` tags

Comment: share minimum code to reproduce the issue. May be you can skip the php code, just share the generated HTML + css from which issue is reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done with display flex.

```
.wrapper {
    display: flex;
}
.column {
    flex: 0 0 33%; // column does not grow or shrink. but takes up 33% of the space
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#native {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: center;
}
```

Comment: When I use this - on smaller screens, the three columns are no longer responsive.